# Xcode Asset Catalog compiler error

Tags: image, launch

[image]

This is the error I get only when I try *archive* my app. I tried to delete the image and re add it etc. nothing is working. I saw some other question that was very similar to this question and the guy was able to fix it by messing with a Terminal. When answering my question please bear in mind that I am new to this. This is my first app, and I would appreciate it if you could dumb down your responses haha thanks

Solution attempts:

- deleting and re adding image
- adding a new image in its place
- cleaning and rebuilding
- deleting derived data and rebuilding
- crying

Comment: Have you tried Clean Build Folder… (Option+Shift+Command+K) ?

Comment: just tried, didn't work