# Bundle is invalid Xcode publishing error

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

[image]

"This bundle is invalid. The icon file Allie VS Shannon.app/LaunchImage-Portrait@2x~ipad.png must be in .png format."

This is the error I get when I try to submit my archive to the app store. It gets to the part where it tries to verify assets with iTunes and then I get this error. I've tried many things, and I know that this is in fact a .png file and not just named .png.

I have "compress png files" turned off because if it is on I get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766544/xcode-asset-catalog-compiler-error?noredirect=1#comment51466001_31766544) when I try to archive my app.

solution attempts

- cleaning and rebuilding
- deleting derived data and rebuilding
- re saving image/deleting and re adding
- resizing image
- i also tried using about 5 different photo editors and saved them as .png files and it still didn't work

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of error messages. Unlike text they are not searchable, and other people with the same problem will not find this question.

Comment: Good point. I edited my question to include the error message as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened up the image assets folder in finder and deleted the entries that were causing trouble (there was a duplicate "-1" image). Then i opened up my images in Preview and resaved them. Then I re added them to the project and everything ran smoothly! Now I'm waiting for App Store approval!

Answer (score 0):

Check your image files really are .png files. Open them up with a hex editor and check the format. If the file begins with FF D8 FF it is a JPEG file, no matter what the file extension is.